# How to get child pages and filter by category?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress page and I've used the plugin api to allow categories for pages. I want to get the child pages, but I want to filter which ones I get by category. I was using the get_page_children_as_html() function, but that wont let me filter my results.

Is there a simple way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin API probably created its own functions to handle the categories, therefore there wouldn't be anything to help you filter a plugins function, you'd have to get in contact with the plugin developers and see if that is possible.

Comment: I created the function myself to allow categories. I want to find out how to retrieve those categories only in connection to the child pages.